# Jquery Mobile radio buttons don't react to change

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

None of my functions work, only when I delete the radio button classes am I able to get a reaction from the radio buttons.

I've tried all of these, and some more, couldn't add all because "too much code".

```
        //$('input:radio[name="jobber"]').change(
    //    function () {
    //        refreshDisplay();
    //    });

    //$("input[name='jobber']").on("change", function () {
    //    refreshDisplay();
    //});

    //$(document).on('change', 'input:radio[name="jobber"]', function () {
    //    alert("Changed!");
    //});
```

HTML:

```
 <form>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <input type="radio" name="jobber" id="radioPaagaaende" value="on" checked="checked">
            <label for="radioPaagaaende">Pågående jobber</label>
            <input type="radio" name="jobber" id="radioFullfort" value="off">
            <label for="radioFullfort">Fullførte jobber</label>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

To update my answer
[This doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXfAC.png)

When I remove a class to the radio button and make it look like this:
[This works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBW3O.png)

Then it works, but obviously I want the look of the first image.

MANAGED TO GET IT WORKING:

```
    <form>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <input type="radio" name="jobber" id="radioPaagaaende" value="on" onchange="myfunction();" checked="checked">
            <label for="radioPaagaaende">Pågående jobber</label>
            <input type="radio" name="jobber" id="radioFullfort" onchange="myfunction();" value="off">
            <label for="radioFullfort">Fullførte jobber</label>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

the JS:

```
        window.myfunction = function() {
        alert("hellooo");
    }
```

Comment: your question is not clear. what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I'm trying to make the on changed work. So that a function fires each time a radio button is clicked.

Comment: check the fiddle once

Answer (score -1):

You need to work with `each()` [Each on jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

[Created a JSFiddle for you](https://jsfiddle.net/36u5vdys/)

Comment: @Emsal Got a link to your page? Bet there something more wrong with the code.

Comment: @DannyThunder Hmm, have you seen my updated answer, add some pictures, the code works fine, it's just that the value doesn't change. The only thing I can see that changes is an attribute called data-cacheval, which toggles between being false or true(selected or deselected).

Comment: I got the code from here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/checkboxradio-radio/